# Set default style parameters in Holoviews

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, visualization

[Holoviews](http://ioam.github.io/holoviews/) is a package that helps with visualizing data. I want to set the default colormap for raster images.

In the [holoviews.Options](https://ioam.github.io/holoviews/Tutorials/Options.html) package is described how to set the defaults for various parameters.

Answer (score 2):

There a number of ways of setting style options in HoloViews, most of them detailed [in this Tutorial](http://ioam.github.io/holoviews/Tutorials/Options).

The simplest way if you're using the IPython notebook is to use the provided %opts line magic as follows:

```
%opts Image (cmap='gnuplot2')
```

Note that if you want to apply it only to a subset of Image objects you can give the Image a group like so:

```
%opts Image.GNUPlot (cmap='gnuplot2')
Image(np.random.rand(50,50), group='GNUPlot')
```

If you're not in the IPython notebook or don't want to use the magics, there are also pure Python ways of setting the options. To set a style globally you can:

```
Store.options.Image = hv.Options('style', cmap='gnuplot2')
```

Finally, to discover what the options are, you can call:

```
hv.help(image, visualization=True)
```

Hope that helps. If you have any more questions come find us at [our Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/holoviews).

Comment: From the tutorial it was not clear to me that the %opts things works for the whole ipython notebook. I was confused by the %%opts, which only operates on a single ipython notebook cell.

Answer (score 0):

The default colormap for a rasterimage (matplotlib.imshow) can be set:

```
import holoviews as hv
hv.Store.options.Image.groups['style'] = hv.Store.options.Image.groups['style'](cmap='gnuplot2')
```